How send Image to API Server, not from file but Image
I've tried send image through multipart/form POST method to server.
It mixes string params and stream content.
However, send file is working. With POSTMAN, with C# code, it worked.
But I want send Bitmap(Image), not file.
This code is for send file, and it worked.
HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "some url");
request.Headers.Add("apiKey", "some key");
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StringContent("TEST IMAGE"), "ImageName");
content.Add(new StreamContent(File.OpenRead("C:/Test/Test.jpg")), "Image", "Test.jpg");
content.Add(new StringContent("IMAGE CODE"), "Code");
request.Content = content;

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

So, upload from file is all right.
But I want send image, i.e. PictureBox Image.
However following code always get 400 bad request error.
public static Stream ImageToStream(Image image, ImageFormat format)
{
   var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
   image.Save(stream, format);
   stream.Position = 0;
   return stream;
}

HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "some url");
request.Headers.Add("apiKey", "some key");
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StringContent("TEST IMAGE"), "ImageName");
var imageContent = new StreamContent(ImageToStream(myPictureBox.Image, ImageFormat.jpeg));
content.Add(imageContent, "Image");
content.Add(new StringContent("IMAGE CODE"), "Code");
request.Content = content;

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

What I've done wrong? How can I achieve send image, not file?

What does ImageToStream() contain?

Maybe the api expects a filename as in the working code

stuartd, you can see ImageToStream function on my code. :)

@Sir Rufo, StreamContent parameters changes according to what method I use. When I use File.openRead, it can be just HttpContent / HttpContent, name / HttpContent, name, filename. But when I use Stream, it changes like Stream content / Stream content and buffersize. There is no way to add "filename" parameter if I use Stream content... Maybe that is the case. I will check if there is no filename with File.openRead method.

content.Add(imageContent, "Image"); => content.Add(imageContent, "Image", "Test.jpg");

@Sir Rufo, Yes! It worked! I didn't think about filename is mandatory for server side... (this server is other company's API server, and they did not describe it is needed on their API document. Thanks a lot, It is solved.

Sir Rufo's comment, It solved. I think this API server is expect user to only upload file, not Image. So I change my code for add filename parameter, and it works as charm.
public static Stream ImageToStream(Image image, ImageFormat format)
{
   var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
   image.Save(stream, format);
   stream.Position = 0;
   return stream;
}

HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "some url");
request.Headers.Add("apiKey", "some key");
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StringContent("TEST IMAGE"), "ImageName");
var imageContent = new StreamContent(ImageToStream(myPictureBox.Image, ImageFormat.jpeg));
content.Add(imageContent, "Image", "Test.jpg"); // This is it!
content.Add(new StringContent("IMAGE CODE"), "Code");
request.Content = content;

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


Is a dog without legs dumb (if you call him he will not come to you)? When you send a stream it is only a bunch of bytes but with the filename you send also the mime-type (in fact the name part does not matter but the extension)
